# SML currying question

Tags: recursion, sml, currying

I have a midterm coming up next week and I was just going over the sml notes provided in class. I came across a currying example and I was not sure exactly how it worked.

It is a simple function which computes the power of a number. Here is the function definition:

```
fun pow 0 n = 1 | pow k n = n*pow(k-1)n
```

I'm not sure how this function works when we pass it the following arguments:

```
val x = pow 2 2
```

This is the way I see it:

```
=2*pow(1)2
=2*(2*pow(0)2)2
=2*(2*(1)2)2)
```

The result we should be getting is four but I don't see how we get this result from the steps I have carried out above.

Help Please. Thank-You.

Comment: Wow, who voted to close this? "Off topic"? really? Perhaps we are only allowed to discuss imperative languages?

Comment: @jalf My curry pun was probably too unpalatable.  Too much curry can be a bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, Standard ML of New Jersey, how I miss thee...

Anyway, let me go through this step by step.  Remember that currying, unlike the dinner in front of me (which incidentally is a curry dish), is basically a way of dealing with only one argument at a time to return a new function.  With that in mind, apply the first 2 to the given function.  Since only one pattern matches, you now have a new function -- let's call it "curry":

```
curry n = n * pow 1 n
```

Note that you now have an "inner" version of the pow function to address.  Doing so, again, one pattern matches.  Let's call this inner curried function "rice":

```
rice n = n * pow 0 n
```

And one more, "shrimp" -- but this time, the other pattern matches:

```
shrimp n = 1
```

The recursion has terminated here, so you have:

```
rice n = n * 1
curry n = n * (n * 1)
```

Now, use the second 2 in your original `pow 2 2` with the new `curry` function:

```
curry 2 = 2 * (2 * 1)
```

which of course is 4.

I highly doubt SML names the curried functions in this way, but I hope this does help to understand the concept.  I take no responsibility if it also makes you hungry.

Answer (score 1):

```
2*pow(1)2 =2*(2*pow(0)2)2
```

Here you expand `pow 1` to `2 * pow 0 2` and leave the 2 after it be. This is wrong. `pow 1` on its own would expand to `(fn n => n * pow 0 2)`, only when applying it to the second argument as well it becomes `2 * pow 0 2`. So the above should read:

```
2*pow(1)2 =2*(2*pow(0)2)
```

Now if we apply `pow 0 2`, we get 1 so the end result is:

```
2*pow(1)2 = 2*(2*pow(0)2) = 2*(2*1) = 4
```